# Jointed wheel spins forever despite specifying damping, friciton and inertial values

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have a cylinder with a revolute joint on a block. The block is grounded to the world. Here's an image of how my setup looks like:

[image: image description]

To test if my mesh is spinning in the right axis, I then give the joint a position in degrees (right hand window).

After specifying inertial values for both the cylinder and the block, I realize that I was probably under specifying the physics of the model. I then added damping and friction components on the revolute joint.

Even after a long time, the wheel never stopped spinning. Any ideas? Am I specifying something incorrectly?

```
   <joint type="revolute" name="base_to_wheel">
    <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
    <child>wheel</child>
    <parent>base_block</parent>
    <axis>
      <xyz>1 0 0</xyz>
      <dynamics>
        <damping>0.50</damping>
        <friction>0.75</friction>
      </dynamics>
    </axis>
  </joint>

  <joint type="revolute" name="ground_link">
    <parent>world</parent>
    <child>base_block</child>
    <axis> <xyz> 0 0 1.0</xyz>
    <limit>
      <lower>0.0</lower>
      <upper>0.0</upper>
    </limit>
    <dynamics/>
    </axis>
  </joint>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1049/jointed-wheel-spins-forever-despite-specifying-damping,-friciton-and-inertial-values/) by [stevenjensj](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/172/stevenjensj/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-01-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The GUI widget your are using is a position based PID controller. It's possible that the default values for the PID controller in the GUI widget are not tuned to your model.

You could try using the "Force" tab. Apply a small force to start the wheel spinning, and then apply a force of zero. The wheel should slowly spin to a stop.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0